# MYSQL UPDATING a table using Four INNER JOINS

Tags: mysql

I have a query that returns the correct values:

```
SELECT cnl.id         cID,
       snl.id         sID,
       cnl.fk_lei     cnl,
       sid.lei        sid,
       cnl.fk_cnty_id cCid,
       snl.fk_cnty_id sCid,
       sec.id         secID,
       sid.id         sidID
FROM   cici.name_loc cnl
       INNER JOIN se4.name_loc snl
               ON snl.legal_name = cnl.legal_name
                  AND snl.fk_cnty_id = cnl.fk_cnty_id
       INNER JOIN se4.sym_exch_cnty sec
               ON sec.id = snl.fk_sec_id
       INNER JOIN se4.identifiers sid
               ON sid.fk_sec_id = sec.id
                  AND sid.lei = 'NA'
WHERE  cnl.legal_name = 'Apple Inc.'
```

```
+------+------+----------------------+-----+------+------+-------+-------+
| cID  | sID  | cnl                  | sid | cCid | sCid | secID | sidID |
+------+------+----------------------+-----+------+------+-------+-------+
| 2010 | 3104 | HWUPKR0MPOU8FGXBT394 | NA  |  233 |  233 | 13756 |  9722 |
+------+------+----------------------+-----+------+------+-------+-------+
```

I would like to modify this so that I can update a field in a table used in the query.
So in the above result the field ' sid' would be updated from 'NA' to 'HWUPKR0MPOU8FGXBT394'

To be exact the 'identifiers' table has a column 'sid.lei' that needs to be
changed from 'NA' to the value in the 'cnl.fk_lei' table.column - only when all of the criteria in the above select is met. I only want to change the one record, not all the records in the table.

I have tried several routes they all give the same error:
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'HWUPKR0MPOU8FGXBT394-NA-NA-NA-1-1' for key 'mk_ident__6fks'

This is tellin me that the update is getting it wrong.

Here is one of the updates I tried:

```
UPDATE identifiers AS b
       INNER JOIN cici.name_loc cnl
               ON cnl.legal_name = 'Apple Inc.'
       INNER JOIN se4.name_loc snl
               ON snl.legal_name = cnl.legal_name
                  AND snl.fk_cnty_id = cnl.fk_cnty_id
       INNER JOIN se4.sym_exch_cnty sec
               ON sec.id = snl.fk_sec_id
SET    b.lei = cnl.fk_lei
WHERE  cnl.legal_name = 'Apple Inc.'
```

In this instance I am only trying to update one record. However, I have hundreds of 
records where snl.legal_name = cnl.legal_name and I will need to update all of them with the numbers in cnl.fk_lei.

Any ideas are most appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to put `sid.lei = 'NA'`(missing) in place of `cnl.legal_name = 'Apple Inc.'`(already present in join condition) in where:

```
   UPDATE identifiers AS b
   INNER JOIN cici.name_loc cnl
           ON cnl.legal_name = 'Apple Inc.'
   INNER JOIN se4.name_loc snl
           ON snl.legal_name = cnl.legal_name
              AND snl.fk_cnty_id = cnl.fk_cnty_id
   INNER JOIN se4.sym_exch_cnty sec
           ON sec.id = snl.fk_sec_id
   SET    b.lei = cnl.fk_lei
   WHERE  sid.lei = 'NA'
```

Comment: I changed the last line of your example so: WHERE  b.lei = 'NA'
but I still get the same error: ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'HWUPKR0MPOU8FGXBT394-NA-NA-NA-1-1' for key 'mk_ident__6fks'
mysql>

Comment: @John: This is your constraint name `mk_ident__6fks`. Which table is having this constraint and what is the relationship? Also, is the any row already in identifiers table with `lei` as `HWUPKR0MPOU8FGXBT394-NA-NA-NA-1-1`??

Comment: It is on the identifier table. The row and field the UPDATE is trying to post to is not correct. I know this because of the "...-NA-1-1" - this is the row that has the correct fk_lei value the "HK.....394" value. If the update worked the line "NA-NA-NA-NA-13756-3104" woule become after the update: "HWUPKR0MPOU8FGXBT394-NA-NA-NA-13756-3104". I hope that helps. Thanks.

Comment: After the update I will have two rows: "HWUPKR0MPOU8FGXBT394-NA-NA-NA-13756-3104" (the good one), and "HWUPKR0MPOU8FGXBT394-NA-NA-NA-1-1" ( this one will then be deleted). I am using the INNER JOINS to make sure that I have found the correct row to get a valid id number, and the corresponding row that needs to be updated. I am using name and country to do this.

Comment: @John When you are updating sid with `HWUPKR0MPOU8FGXBT394`, how is this coming `HWUPKR0MPOU8FGXBT394-NA-NA-NA-1-1`?? Is some concatenation happening somewhere? You need to share little more details to enable a better help.

Comment: cici.name_loc (cnl) has legal_name, fk_cnty_id, fk_lei. se4.name_loc (snl) has legal_name, fk_cnty_id and foreign key fk_sec_id which is primary key for se4.sym_exch_cnty. se4.sym_exch_cnty(sec) references other tables. se4.identifiers (sid) has fk_sec_id, lei. I need to match the entity in cnl (the cici DB) to the entities referenced in the se4 D.B., and all I have to make the match is the legal_name, fk_cnty_id (country code), and a record in se4.sym_exch_cnty. The identifiers table has two entries (rows) one with only the lei set, and the other where fk_sec_id & fk_n_l_id are set (not 1).

Comment: There is no concatenation, the query (which works) returns two values of interest "sid" is "NA" and "cnl" is "HWUPKR0MPOU8FGXBT394". To generate those values I had to locate a particular row in the identifiers table (it has the "NA" value). What I want to do is take the "HWUPKR0MPOU8FGXBT394" value which comes from "cnl.fk_lei" and insert it into the record "sid.lei" on the same row that the select originally found. I have solved it somewhat by creating a temp. table and inserting the desired fields into it. This works, I would prefer to use an update. I guess I am not explaining it very well.

Answer (score 1):

Below is UPDATE syntax from [MySQL website](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
[WHERE where_condition]
[ORDER BY ...]
[LIMIT row_count]
```

What you want to do is the following:

```
UPDATE identifiers AS b
   SET b.lei = (select cnl.fk_lei
                  from cici.name_loc cnl
            INNER JOIN se4.name_loc snl  ON snl.legal_name = cnl.legal_name 
                   and snl.fk_cnty_id = cnl.fk_cnty_id
            INNER JOIN se4.sym_exch_cnty sec ON sec.id = snl.fk_sec_id
                 where cnl.legal_name = 'Apple Inc.')
```

note that this going to update all `identifiers` rows, you may want to add `where clause` to the update to limit its impact.

Comment: I only want to modify one row which meets the criteria. Would I insert the where clause after .... 'Apple Inc.') ?